# How to add a Kotlin class in an Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have been working with Android Studio for a while. Recently I have heard about kotlin programming language and I wanted to try to include a class in kotlin language to my project.

There is the problem that whenevr I want to create a new Activity for example, the **.java** class is auto-generated. Also I see no way to cretae a **.kt** (kotlin) file manually.

So does anyone know how to setup a **.kt** file in Android Studio, so that I am able to fill it with code in kotlin language?

Comment: Right Click on **java** project directory -> **new** -> select **"Kotlin File/Class"**.

Comment: Putting this here for future devs... After I created a brand-new project (in Android Studio 3.1.3) that includes Kotlin support, I did not have the  **File -> New -> Kotlin File/Class** until AFTER I did a Gradle sync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, install Kotlin plugin in Android Studio. Restart Android Studio.
Now create a new project with no activity.
Then navigate to `src>main>java><your_package_name>`.
Right Click on `<your_package_name>`, select New>Kotlin Activity and go ahead with configuration.
Now naviagte to `src>main>java><your_package_name>/<activity_name>.kt` and open it.
After opening it, you will see `Kotlin not configured` message.
Just click configure action and run your project. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by converting Java file to Kotlin file.
Open the java class, and from menu bar choose `Code` -> `Convert Java File to Kotlin File`.

Answer (score 0):

Get Android Studio 3 preview and when you start a new project click the option to add Kotlin support... Once in your project you'll see options to create Kotlin class when you right click